# Extracting a value using xpath

Tags: php, xpath

how can I get the `value` of this input using xpath?

```
<input type='text' name='name' value='john' />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the attribute selector, eg: `//input/@value`

There's more about selecting nodes here: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) and a nice tool for testing your [XPath here](http://emdin-here.ru/r/xpath_checker/).

Answer (score 2):

i think

```
//input/@value
```

would be enough if you had only this piece of code... but maybe you have more html around and you need to target :

```
//input[@name='name']/@value
```

Answer (score 1):

With SimpleXML,

```
$input_element = $your_xml_doc->xpath("//input[@name='name']");
$value = (String) $input_element[0]->attributes()->value;
```